# Личные сообщения. Вывод диалогов

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы.

```
[users]

 - id
 - name

[prmess]

 - id
 - date
 - from_id
 - to_id
 - text
 - view (boolean) 1/0
```

Собственно с выводом данных конкретного диалога/добавлением сообщений и т.п. проблем нет. Возникает проблема с выводом списка диалогов. То есть сообщения от меня к пете, и от пети ко мне это один диалог, а как составить запрос таким образом? более того нужно как-то суммировать непрочитанные сообщения (view) в этом диалоге только от собеседника (исключая свои).
На выходе должно получиться что то вроде:

1. Собеседник [Петя], непрочитанных сообщений [2], id собесед.=2
2. Собеседник [Вася], непрочитанных сообщений [5], id собесед.=3
3. Собеседник [Женя], непрочитанных сообщений [0], id собесед.=4
4. Собеседник [Коля], непрочитанных сообщений [1], id собесед.=5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select name,sum(not_view) msg_cnt,int_id
  from (
        select if(from_id=1,to_id,from_id) int_id, 1-view not_view
          from prmess
         where from_id=1 or to_id=1
       ) A
  join users2 on id=int_id
 group by int_id
```