# Выбор последних сообщений из диалогов пользователей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Aincrad\Models\Messages
WHERE author = :author: OR recipient = :author: 
GROUP BY author, recipient ORDER BY id DESC

array (
    'author' => $auth['login'],
    'recipient' => $auth['login']
)
```

Результаты выполнения запроса (если переменная `$auth['login']` равна 'Gildars'):

[image: Результаты выполнения запроса для пользователя с ником Gildars]
Я делаю список активных диалогов пользователя, и мне нужно написать запрос, который вернет последнее сообщение из переписки двух пользователей.
Но на скриншоте видно, что в результатах выборки есть **две** записи из переписки пользователей 'Gildars' и 'Haruka', а мне нужна только одна запись из их переписки.
Как исключить подобные дубликации?

Comment: Речь про последнее сообщение из конкретного диалога между _Gildars_ и _Haruka_ или же про последние сообщения из каждого диалога (по одному на каждый диалог), в котором участвует _Gildars_?

Comment: И что такое "последнее сообщение", никаких дат сообщений или чего то подобного тут не видно. Как определить какое из них последнее. И посмотрите вот этот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541842/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2/541850#541850 ответ. Там очень похожая ситуация. Вам надо группировку делать не по двум пользователям, а с помощью `if` сформировать единственного ответственного за диалог. Либо поменять их местами, для некоторых записей

Comment: речь идет про последние сообщения из каждого диалога (по одному на каждый диалог), в котором участвует Gildars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По аналогии с [ответом Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541842/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2/541850#541850):

```
SELECT Messages.*
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS 'maxid', IF (author = 'Gildars', recipient, author) AS 'user'
    FROM Messages
    WHERE author = 'Gildars' or recipient = 'Gildars'
    GROUP BY user
) AS a
INNER JOIN Messages ON a.maxid = id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Во внутреннем запросе выбираем максимальный ID сообщения для каждого пользователя, участвовавшего в переписке с заданным пользователем.
Во внешнем - по полученным ID выбираем сами сообщения.

[Пример в SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3ef8/1).