# Выбрать свежие записи в таблице mysql, где уникальность записи определяется через несколько полей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `tests` результатов тестирования людей в нескольких компаниях.

```
(company_id BIGINT - идентификатор компании,
test_id BIGINT PRIMARY - идентификатор теста,
name VARCHAR - имя тестируемого,
surname VARCHAR - фамилия,
email VARCHAR - емейл тестируемого,
result VARCHAR - результаты тестирования,
started DATE - дата теста,
is_deleted BOOL - живое ли приглашение
и еще несколько полей)
```

Каждый человек может пройти в компании несколько тестов. Затрудняюсь выбрать последний тест по каждому человеку. Уникальность определяется совокупностью полей name, surname, email и company_id.

Запрос:

```
SELECT name, surname, email, test_id, result FROM tests
WHERE company_id='$comp_id' AND is_deleted=0
```

...выдает все тесты, пройденные в этой компании.
Как отсеять старые тесты, оставить в таблице только последний тест по каждому человеку (человек определяется совокупностью `name, surname, email`)?

То есть из выборки убрать те записи, где `name, surname, email` одни и те же, но дата `started` старее последней записи.

Спасибо!

Comment: Что то вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543826/194569 только group by в подзапросе по всем полям уникальности и их же сравнение в ON.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Нашел решение: SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, MAX(`started`) FROM tests WHERE company_id='$comp_id' AND is_deleted=0 GROUP BY `name`,`surname`, `email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, surname, email, MAX(started) FROM tests
WHERE company_id='$comp_id' AND is_deleted=0
GROUP BY name, surname, email
```

Этот запрос решил задачу.